# Is it possible to create a CSV file and make ZIp download in phalcon

Tags: csv, zip, phalcon

I am searching for the CSV file creation in Phalcon .I got some CSV documentation in phalcon but it was not giving clear idea.Can some one post the code for it.Thanks in Advance.

```
namespace Business\Controllers\API;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
use Phalcon\Http\Response;

class DownloadController extends \Business\Controllers\API\ApiControllerBase
```

{

```
public function createZipAction()
{   

        // create your zip file
        $zipname = 'bvcards.zip';
        $zip = new \ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

      echo "here i am";
      exit;
 }
```

}

The above code not executing because Zip Archive making some issue.

Comment: Phalcon does not provide such libraries. That's the beauty of the framework, it is not stuffed with things you will never use like others frameworks and gives you the freedom to use own or other libraries for custom scenarios for example Email sending.

Comment: i am trying to Zip the file but Zip archive is not working in Phalcon ?is ther any reson ?

Comment: Update your question with code sample, what have you tried so far? I doubt there are mind readers here :)

Comment: I have added my code kindly update me..Thanks in Advance

Comment: even i tried like this   $zip = new ZipArchive;

Answer (score 1):

The same like in PHP. Please check fgetcsv function: http://php.net//manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example:

```
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $filename = 'test.zip';

    if ($zip->open($filename, \ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
    }        
    $zip->addFile('robots.txt', '.htaccess'); 
    $zip->close();
```

Note the \ before ZipArchive in the open() method. You are missing it and you were probably receiving namespace error.

**Please note: in the current example used and generated files are relative to the index.php since in my example this is my bootstrap file. You should set paths according to your configuration.**

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me .

```
namespace Business\Controllers\API;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
use Phalcon\Http\Response;
use ZipArchive;

class DownloadController extends \Business\Controllers\API\ApiControllerBase

{

public function createZipAction()
{   

    // create your zip file
    $zipname = 'bvcards.zip';
    $zip = new \ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

  echo "here i am";
  exit;
```

}

}